# Linear Algebra: Find the parametric equations...

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the parametric equations of the line parallel to the line of intersection of the two planes $x+2y-z=4$ and $x-y+3z=6$, and that passes through the point $(2,-3,5)$.

Comment: What have you tried? No one is gonna answer if you do not show what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- The line of intersection is perpendicular to the normal vectors of each of the planes
- We can completely specify a line by a point on the line and a parallel vector